# Acer Aspire E1-572G doesn't wake up

Tags: laptop, drivers, windows-8.1, sleep, acer-aspire

I recently got a new Acer Aspire E1-572G and every time I sleep it closing the lid it is impossible to wake it up.

I applied the solutions to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/702956/acer-aspire-e1-572g-wont-wake-up-from-sleep) but the problem persists.

I already had fast boot disabled and the installed GPU drivers are the following:

- AMD 13.201.0.0
- Intel 10.18.10.3355

What can I do?

Comment: Try pressing the Fn key for switching display output or Win+P. If that doesn't work, try disabling power saving on the keyboard in Device Manager and enable "Allow this device to wake the computer"

Comment: @wiz3kid thanks, Fn+F6 worked. Anyway, that kind of the less intuitive way to make this work. Is there any way moving the mouse or pressing any key would do it (just like every laptop in the planet)?

Comment: Check this Q: http://superuser.com/questions/23820/windows-7-vista-laptop-monitor-does-not-come-back-after-closing-lid

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I solved my problem by 
1. pressing the power button for a longer period for de pc to go off.
2. changing the ram from one slot to another and opening the lid. That worked for me

Comment: You need to pull the battery out before holding down the power button. If you can't pull the battery out, the method will probably not work.